docker.io/nginx on podman started by gitlab-runner cannot be shut down
I am working on Ubuntu 24 (Noble). Thereon runs a gitlab-runner in root. The gitlab ci pipeline builds and starts podman containers.
My issue is that an nginx container hosting my webpage cannot be stopped and some zombie will live on.
Steps to reproduce (you don't need a gitlab runner):
Dockerfile:
FROM docker.io/nginx:alpine as ui
# Copy the build output from the previous image

docker-compose.yaml
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
    expose:
      - "80"

Then run:
sudo podman-compose build
sudo podman-compose up -d
sudo podman-compose down

The last command will not be able to shut down the containers as can be verified in:
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                        COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS                   NAMES
62e8ba97cc19  localhost/ui_frontend:latest   nginx -g daemon o...  47 minutes ago  Shutting down 12 minutes ago  127.0.0.1:80->80/tcp  ui_frontend_1

The resulting container cannot be force removed, the files associated with the container cannot be removed.
When running podman without elevation, I have no issues. What is the best strategy here?
Kind Regards

the issue related to this question was actually a bug in AppArmor, that to this day hasn't been fixed. AppArmor profiles capture SIGINT, SIGKILL signals in rootful podman containers.
The solution is to downgrade from Ubuntu 24 to Ubuntu 22.
Kind Regards
